# How to implement personalized product in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce site for logo or banner design. And the requirement is, in the time of add to cart a product customer have to answer some question which will product related. Customer can tell what type of logo he/she want. Any specific color combination or any special requirement etc.

So, for this type of requirement is there any plugin(free/paid) in woocommerce or wordpress? If yes please send me the link, and if no then any idea that how can I implement this.
All suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a plugins from wordpress official site. I think you need to implement the following plugins.

[image: personalized product]
[This plugin allow WooCommerce store admin to add four types of input so user can add data before checkout to personalize the order.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-addon/screenshots/)